# Hover from one object to another without the second DOM object disappearing right away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Target:** Object user will hover over to bring up secondary DOM
**Tooltip:** Fixed DOM object positioned about 10-15px below **target**

I have made a jquery **"tooltip" plugin**. This plugin allows users to **hover** over a DOM object, and **will show the "tooltip"**. I want users to be able to ***move their mouse from the target to the tooltip without it disappearing*** the second their mouse leaves the target.

I have tried this:

```
 var hoverTimeout;

                data.target.hover(function(){
                    $this.tooltip('show');
                }, function(){

                    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                        $this.tooltip('hide');
                        console.log('hey');
                    }, 1000);

                });

                data.tooltip.hover(function(){
                    data.tooltip('show');
                    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
                }, function(){
                    data.tooltip('hide');
                });
```

However, this seems to stop the Tooltip from hiding. The reason I'd like to do this, is so forms can be used, text can be copied, etc., in the tooltip.

I'm hoping something like a setTimeout and clearTimeout will work as I don't want to use hoverintent plugin.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: var hoverTimeout;
                  
data.target.hover(function()
{
 $this.tooltip('show');
 clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
}, function()
{
 hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
  $this.tooltip('hide');
 }, 1000);

});

data.tooltip.hover(function()
{
 $this.tooltip('show');
 clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
}, function()
{
 hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
  $this.tooltip('hide');
 }, 1000);
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the timer both ways:

```
var hoverTimeout;

data.target.hover(function()
{
    hoverTimeout && clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    $(this).tooltip('show');
},
function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $this.tooltip('hide');
    }, 1000);

});

data.tooltip.hover(function()
{
    hoverTimeout && clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
},
function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $this.tooltip('hide');
    }, 1000);
});
```

---

You should probably [combine the two](http://api.jquery.com/add/), since you're anyhow doing the exact same thing on both of them:

```
var hoverTimeout;

data.target.add( data.tooltip ).hover(function()
{
    hoverTimeout && clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    $(this).tooltip('show');
},
function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $this.tooltip('hide');
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could even set the timeout to more than a second in case the user can't mouse over to the tooltip quickly enough?

Comment: Thank you very much. And it's VERY close to the object. If they take more then a second, they shouldn't be using my app ;) haha just kidding :). But one second is sufficient. I'm not sure why you're redefining this, as that caused an error. I also found my code to be 90% correct. I missed a .hide() somewhere else in the code, which is why it wouldn't disappear. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explain this part? 
    hoverTimeout && clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);

Comment: @iRedMedia - This is a shorthand version of an `if` statement. It's the same as: `if (hoverTimeout) { clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); }`. The first time someone hovers over your element, the `hoverTimeout` variable will be `undefined`, so that `clearTimeout(hoverTimeout)` will give you an error; so we first check to be sure that `hoverTimeout` is not `undefined` before we call `clearTimeout` on it.

Comment: @iRedMedia - Check out the update to my answer on how to combine the 2 hover listeners.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Already using the '.add' in my method! Thanks for the help though, appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
var hoverTimeout;

data.target.hover(function()
{
    $this.tooltip('show');
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
}, function()
{
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $this.tooltip('hide');
    }, settings.delay);
});

data.tooltip.hover(function()
{

    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
}, function()
{
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $this.tooltip('hide');
    }, settings.delay);
});
```